# User Agent Style overriding Font in one language

Tags: asp.net, localization, styles, agent, overriding

I am hoping for some direction or clues on tracking down a defect.

I have a ul side menu with links to aspx pages

A subset of these pages render the menu items in italic when the language is *French only*.

When this happens the console shows a new style entry for the menu items:

*inherited from i:*

```
i, cite, em, var, address, dfn {
font-style: italic;
```

- The aspx pages that are affected have the same header and links to
  styles as those that are not affected.
- The pages render fine in other
  languages
- The problem exists in Chrome but not Explorer
- There are no in-line styles on the aspx pages
- The user style overrides my
  style sheet even when I add the following to it as a test:

  i {font-style: none !important;}

Any thoughts on what might cause the user agent style to take priority?

Comment: Please provide a demo that illustrates the problem – preferably a minimal HTML document, but a URL of the actual page is better than nothing. Also please specify what you mean by “the language is”. (Browser UI language? OS language? Document language? Something else?) Note that `font-style: none` has no effect, because `none` is not a defined value for `font-style`; `normal` is.

Comment: My incorrect font-style syntax was at fault.  Once I set this properly the agent style was overridden.  Providing an example was difficult given the page is a private SaaS app and I was unable to re-produce the issue on a new page.  Thanks though.